# Error in My PHP

Tags: php

```
[16-Aug-2013 01:38:56 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/lineage/public_html/includes/templates/activate.php on line 21
```

Archive:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($included) || !$included) exit();

    if ($hash->validate($_GET['serial']))
        if ($_handlerLoginServer->exec($_queryLogin['activateAccount'],array($_GET['serial'])) > 0) {
            $account = $_handlerLoginServer->select($_queryLogin['accountSerial'],array($_GET['serial']));
            if ($cookie->set("referral")) {
                if (!$_handlerLoginServer->select($_queryLogin['checkIP'],array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])))
                    $_handlerLoginServer->execute($_queryLogin['increaseReferral'],array($cookie->get("referral")));
                    $playerInfo = $_handlerLoginServer->select($_queryLogin['selectPlayer'],array($cookie->get("referral")));
                    if ($playerInfo[3] % 10 == 0) {
                        $balance->increase($playerInfo[1],$_config['referralReward']);
                        $log->add($log->format($_lang['log']['referralReward'],array($_config['referralReward'])),$playerInfo[1]);
                    }
                }
                $cookie->delete("referral");
            }
            $log->add($_lang['log']['activatedAccount'],$account[0]);

            $_templatePage->replace("feedback",$_lang['success']['activateAccount']);
        } else
            $_templatePage->replace("feedback",$_lang['error']['activateAccount']);
    } else
        $_templatePage->replace("feedback",$_lang['error']['serialFormat']);
?>
```

Comment: throw an open curly on the end of line 4

Comment: @vinodadhikary you might as well edit the question to make it the answer!

Comment: @Prasanth, I'm waiting for some answer that states, at least practice open and closing braces, that's a good programming habit.  Just because you don't need it (for a single line block, so called) doesn't mean you have to ignore it, and eventually get into this mess.

Comment: @vinodad it's reaching to call that a bad programming practice. More of a typo/oversight.   One can always use a text-editor or IDE that assists with that stuff but its still easy to miss.  Luckily the error log pointed out the exact problem.  Better idea would be to improve at reading the log, which hopefully will come with experience.

Comment: @NeilNeyman, Agreed. I didn't mean bad programming practice, I meant adding them would be "good programming practice".  I've appreciated the indentation on his code though, yet this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Line 4 and 8 you need to add an opening brace

change line 4

```
if ($hash->validate($_GET['serial']))
```

to

```
if ($hash->validate($_GET['serial'])) {
```

change line 8

```
if (!$_handlerLoginServer->select($_queryLogin['checkIP'],array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])))
```

to

```
if (!$_handlerLoginServer->select($_queryLogin['checkIP'],array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))) {
```

Comment: you add a typo, so I edited

Answer (score 0):

Go to line 4, and add an open squiggily bracket:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($included) || !$included) exit();

    if ($hash->validate($_GET['serial'])){
```